# Gmail API import AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp and LocalServerReceiver Clases

Tags: java, gmail-api

I am trying to create a java file which will send an email.
I created a Google web application projects, configured it (hoping I did it properly) and then followed the [Java Quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java).

Though I can't import these classes (guessing that therefore also can't run the file):

```
com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post your error details

Comment: When I try to compile the java file I get this error: GmailQuickStart.java: 1: error: package com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthrizationCodeInstalledApp does not exist. Import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Maven, then add these two dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```